# Where do I need to put the yaml file for VichUploaderBundle in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I am having trouble installing the bundle. I have followed the instruction in the document. I have successfully installed the package as I saw the vich folder created in the vendor folder. And I have created and put the `vich_uploader.yaml` file inside `config/packages` folder. However, when I got to the end of the second step [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-2-link-the-upload-mapping-to-an-entity) and ran the console clear cache command, I got the errors

> In FileLoader.php line 166:
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "vich_uploader"... Looked for namespace "vich_uploader",
>   found "framework", "web_server", "twig"   , "sensio_framework_extra",
>   "maker", "web_profiler", "monolog", "debug", "doctrine_cache",
>   "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security" in ...
>
> In YamlFileLoader.php line 666:
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "vich_uploader"... Looked for namespace "vich_uploader",
>   found "framework", "web_server", "twig"   , "sensio_framework_extra",
>   "maker", "web_profiler", "monolog", "debug", "doctrine_cache",
>   "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security"

When I removed that yaml file, everything works fine again.

Answer (score 2):

Add your bundle in `config/bundles.php`

```
return [
  ...
  Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle::class => ['all' => true]
  ...
]
```

If you are using Symfony Flex, the bundle and config should be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what's wrong with my problem. On my installation, there's an option asking me to install a recipe with the yellow warning sign next to it, so I thought it might be something and chose "no".

It works fine now after I reinstalled the package with that recipe.